# how to validate dynamically created textfields in flutter

Tags: validation, flutter, textfield

**the value of the boolean variable changes but it doesn't show error text on text field**

*these are the declarations*

```
    int i = 0;
    List<bool> validationList = [];
    List<Widget> listDynamic = [];
    List<TextEditingController> controllersList = [];
```

*this is the method for validation*

```
    submitData()
    {
    for(int a = 0 ; a < i; a++ ){
        if(controllersList[a].text == ''){
            setState(() {
                validationList[a] =true;
                print(validationList[a]);
            });
        }
    }
    }
```

*this is the method for creating text fileds dynamically*

```
    addDynamic() {
    validationList = List.from(validationList)..add(false);
    controllersList = List.from(controllersList)..add(TextEditingController());
    listDynamic = List.from(listDynamic)..add(Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 20, 0),
            child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    errorText: validationList[i] == true ? 'Value cant be empty' : null,
                    labelText: ('ImageURL'),
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.image),
                    helperText: 'www.example.com',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    controller: controllersList[i],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
        ],
      ));
      i++;
    setState(() {});
    }
```

Comment: to make this easier, you could use the flutter form builder library : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder  and just dynamically add the new FormBuilderTextField to the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'key' property to the TextField:
key: ObjectKey("key$i"),